# Upgrading to 14.04 LTS when 16.04 LTS is available

Tags: 14.04, 12.04, upgrade

I want to upgrade my desktop and I don't want 16.04 yet. I've been all over and I can't find anything that says "Enter this command and your desktop will upgrade from 12.04 LTS to 14.04 LTS and NOT 16.04 LTS."

I'm running Kubuntu 12.04 LTS i386 desktop. I want to enter a command and upgrade to 14.04, NOT 16.04.

Comment: According to this you can't skip from 12.04 to 16.04 in the first place: http://askubuntu.com/questions/34430/can-i-skip-over-releases-when-upgrading

Comment: The do-release-upgrade program will show you what it wants to do and gives you a chance to back out.

Answer (score 0):

Try opening the Update Manager application and installing all updates avaliables.
Check the ubuntu release to update.

Launch the Terminal and type:

```
sudo update-manager -d
```

[image]

**`Enter`**, and then enter your user password when prompted.

The Update Manager application will open. Click the button to begin the process. The whole process could take some time